# Is it possible to make this recursive function point-free?

Tags: haskell

I have a simple function, and the desire to make sense of point-free style.

```
shout :: String -> String
shout input
  | null input = []
  | otherwise = (toUpper . head $ input) : (shout . tail $ input)
```

My intuition led me to this

```
pfShout :: String -> String
pfShout = (toUpper . head) : (shout . tail)
```

which is complaining about the following for the first argument of the cons cell

> Couldn't match expected type 'String -> String'
>                 with actual type '[[Char] -> Char]'
>
> - Possible cause: '(:)' is applied to too many arguments
>
>   In the expression: (toUpper . head) : (pfShout . tail)
>
>   In an equation for 'pfShout':
>       pfShout = (toUpper . head) : (pfShout . tail)

and complaining about this for the second argument of the cons cell

> Couldn't match expected type '[[Char] -> Char]'
>                 with actual type '[Char] -> String'
>
> - Probable cause: '(.)' is applied to too few arguments
>
>   In the second argument of '(:)', namely '(pfShout . tail)'
>
>   In the expression: (toUpper . head) : (pfShout . tail)
>
>   In an equation for 'pfShout':
>       pfShout = (toUpper . head) : (pfShout . tail)

It's clear to me that I can't make a list out of 'String -> String' functions *and* '[[Char]->Char]', and I'm starting to get a to a place where I'm thinking this just isn't gonna work point-free.

I understand there are other considerations here (like now I'm missing a base-case), but . I also understand I could completely re-write the function to achieve the same effect (like `map toUpper`). I'm primarily interested in point-free *using recursion* with the function as it is written.

If it is (or isn't) possible to write this function point-free, what am I missing?

Comment: Would `shout = map toUpper` work?

Comment: oh, there are definitely ways to tweak it entirely, but I was wondering if i could make the recursive version point free (as I type this, I'm thinking "maybe recursion is why I can't point-free"). Shoulda made that more explicit in my question

Comment: Assume you have managed to fix `(toUpper . head) : (shout . tail)` (it is possible). How does the recursion end? You need to evaluate some condition. How do you write a condition in a point-free manner?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @n.m noted you can use `shout = map toUpper`. However it is possible to do this without `map` or any other fancy functions like `foldr`, but we need more combinators. We need something that takes our input argument and passes it to two functions `toUpper . head` and `shout . tail` and then combines them with `:`. You propably don't know this function yet,  but the `<*>` operator from applicative has what we need:

```
(f <*> g) x = f x (g x)
```

Now we can do something like this:

```
combine . f <*> g = \x -> combine (f x) (g x) -- [1]
```

I will let you figure out how exactly to apply this to your problem. ;)

But we still need to express the empty list case somehow. There are multiple ways to do this but the easiest would be the `bool` from `Data.Bool` function which is like an `if` function, together with `join` from `Control.Monad`.

```
-- [2]
bool x _ False = x
bool _ x True  = x

join f x = f x x
```

Now we can do the following:

```
shout = join $ bool (not null case) (null case) . null
-- Which translates to
shout xs = bool ((not null case) xs) ((null case) xs) (null xs)
```

Again implementing the two cases is left as an excercise to the reader.

[1]: Instead of `(.)` you could also use `(<$>)` which for functions is the same as `(.)` but `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` kind of belong together. You will understand why once you learn about applicatives.

[2]: If you wonder what the reasoning behind the order of the arguments of `bool` is, the first argument is the `False` case because `Bool` is defined like this:

```
data Bool = False | True
```

And this order is motivated by the convention that `False < True`. `maybe` and `either` are two other functions that share this exact pattern with `bool`.

Comment: Yup, I'm seeing Applicative a few chapters out in my book yet. Thanks for the very thorough reply!

Comment: Does the `Applicative` case work? I was working on an answer along those lines, but I can't seem to get something that type-checks. `shout = (:) <$> (toUpper.head) <*> (shout . tail)` "works" (at least, for infinite lists), but trying to combine this with `bool` results in a type error. `shout = bool ((:) <$> (toUpper . head) <*> (shout . tail)) id . null`.

Comment: @chepner You are just missing the `join`. The `bool` consumes the argument for the predicate and then there is nothing to apply the functions of the two cases to.

Comment: Ah, OK, right. `null` is using the input without passing it through to the correct function. I never gave much thought to what `join` does in the function monad.

Answer (score 2):

To rewrite anything in a pointfree style,  install [pointfree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree)  or use any one of the online versions (http://pointfree.io or https://blunt.herokuapp.com).

Your expression

```
\input -> (toUpper . head $ input) : (shout . tail $ input)
```

translates to

```
ap ((:) . toUpper . head) (shout . tail)
```

(You can substitute `<*>` for `ap`, they are interchangeable in this case).

But this is not enough. You also need to somehow end the recursion. To do that in the pointfree style you need a pointfree `if` or a pointfree pattern match which do not seem to exist in Haskell. In theory `if` could be defined as a built-in function, which would make a pointfree definition possible, but in Haskell it isn't. (One can define such a function, but its implementation would not be pointfree. So you can trade `map` for `Data.Bool.bool`, but is there a point?

Combinators like `.` and `$` and even `ap` are probably not internally pointfree either, but using them doesn't *feel* like cheating. They only deal with functions, and thus feel somehow more fundamental than `bool` or `map`.

Answer (score 1):

The point-free way to do recursion is to use `Data.Function.fix`, which is explained here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Fix_and_recursion

Comment: This is the most practical way to make recursion pointfree. Just gets straight to the nub of the problem